# Remote Desktop access Windows 7 system from Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, firewall, kaspersky

I have 2 windows systems...

1. Windows 7 *(192.168.2.8)*
2. Windows 8 *(192.168.2.9)*

Both are connected to WiFi router. They have been assigned address 192.168.2.8 & 192.168.2.9 respectively. I have added them to home group and I am able to ping and connect Windows 8 system from Windows 7.

I am having trouble connecting to Windows 7 system from Windows 8 system. I can't even ping Windows 7 system. Windows 7 system's user is administrator (default administrator account from secpol.msc). File sharing, Remote Access, network discovery are all enabled. Someone please help me connect.

I found that this is the issue of Kaspersky Internet Security 2012. If I disable firewall, it works. I tried opening port 3389 in Kaspersky. It is still blocking access.

Comment: 3389 TCP right?

Comment: Yes. I followed the approach given in http://support.kaspersky.com/kis2012/settings/firewall?qid=208286427 but still it is blocked.

Comment: try to open 3389 port in Windows Firewall too.

Comment: The Windows Firewall should be off if there's a 3rd-party one. And this kinda reinforces my experience that all kinds of strange things break if you install such crap, hooray :-)

Comment: For what it is worth, this is probably totally on the endpoint, Windows 7, and has little to do with the Windows 8 client end of things. Most firewalls and settings block incoming stuff, not outgoing.

Comment: Windows 7 uses different settings based on the network type it thinks it's connected to: Home Network, Work Network or Public Network. Make sure your Windows 7 computer has the network location set to Home network.

Comment: @Brian You're so right! One time my Windows 7 laptop decided my home network was now a public network, and promptly disallowed RDP connections. Drove me nuts 'til I found it.

Answer (score 1):

I think 3389 is not the only port that must be open on the firewall; check this link for more information directly from the source: 
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Remote-Desktop-Connection-frequently-asked-questions
I'd also try enabling ports 135 and 447